# Service error "... has no zero argument constructor"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I want start a service, I use:

```
inner class HomeService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        notification(light.toString())
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

start it:

```
val i = Intent(this@Main3Activity, HomeService()::class.java)
startService(i)
```

after my app crashed, logcat return:

> java.lang.Class
>   has no zero argument constructor
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1586)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>        Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class
>   has no zero argument constructor
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3198)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1586) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating an instance by hand by writing down `HomeService()` inside your `Intent` creation code. Creating the service is the task of the framework, and you can pass its class without creating an instance:

```
val i = Intent(this@Main3Activity, HomeService::class.java)
startService(i)
```

---

Update:

In addition to the above, your class also can't be an inner class. It can be nested, but it can't be an inner class, because those hold a reference to the class that they're inside. This means that the system can't create an instance of your service on its own - it has no way of providing an outer class for it to reference.

Comment: I registered !!

Comment: Right. it working. But when i pass context: HomeService(val context: Context) : Service() , i get the same error in manifest:  <service
            android:name="com.example.duc25.modules.HomeService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service> with error: "..has no zero argument constructor"

Comment: It's because Service is having a zero argument constructor and You are applying a one value constructor to your HomeService. So you will require two constructors in your HomeService one with the primary constructor and one with the argument you want.
Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058986/9734616

Answer (score 3):

```
class HomeService() : Service() {
    constructor(context: Context) : this() {
        Log.d("TAG","ANOTHER CONSTRUCTOR")
    }
}
```

Now you can use this service by two ways

1. `val intent =  Intent(this@Main3Activity, HomeService::class.java)`
2. `val intent =  Intent(this@Main3Activity, HomeService(context)::class.java)`